# node.js: How to add non-key attribute in DynamoDB while table creation?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I am using  dynamoDB local. I want to create a table with 6 attributes, only one of them is `key`. How do I do that? Specify the key attribute in `keySchema` and all attributes in `AttributeDefinitions`?

```
var params = {
    TableName : "Movies",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
        { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you receiving the following error?

> One or more parameter values were invalid: Number of attributes in
>   KeySchema does not exactly match number of attributes defined in
>   AttributeDefinitions

This is because your `AttributeDefinitions` contains an attribute that is not defined in the `KeySchema`. If you're only going to use a `HASH` key, and not going to need a `RANGE` key, you can remove the `title` attribute from the `AttributeDefinitions`.

`DynamoDB` is schemaless so you don't need to include any non-key attribute definitions in `AttributeDefinitions`. You can add any additional attribute(s) when you put an item in your table (**have to include Partition/Sort keys**).

The following code will create a table with only a `HASH (Partition) key`:

```
var dynamodb = new AWS_SDK.DynamoDB();

var params = {
    TableName : "MyNewTable",
    KeySchema: [
        { AttributeName: "year", KeyType: "HASH"},  //Partition key
        //{ AttributeName: "title", KeyType: "RANGE"},  //Sort key
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
        { AttributeName: "year", AttributeType: "N" },
        // { AttributeName: "title", AttributeType: "S" }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {
        ReadCapacityUnits: 10,
        WriteCapacityUnits: 10
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to create table. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Created table. Table description JSON:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
```

For more info, you can refer to the [AWS SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#createTable-property) for the `createTable` function on the `DynamoDB` service.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: You can't.

You can't add non-key attributes while creating the table. You have to create the table first, then add non-key attributes using `dynamodb.putItem()` or `dynamodb.batchWriteItem()`.

Example:

```
var params = {
  TableName: 'Movies',
  Item: {
    'year': {N: '1994'},
    'title': {S: 'Pulp Fiction'},
    'description': {S: 'Two hitmen with a penchant for philosophical discussions.'},
  }
}

dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
  }
});
```